# How do handle Java runtime errors when running as a cronjob

Tags: java, cron

I am running Java standalone jobs as cronjobs. I noticed that in some rare instances a job will fail with a runtime exception such as OutOfMemoryError. The cron's MAIL_TO handler does not seem to pick up the failure of the job and obviously the Java application is incapable to do anything, as execution stopped due to a memory error.

What would be best practice to handle such errors and have cron alert? The closest I could think of is that each Java job writes a "SUCCESS"-log record and then chain a grep in the cronjob and return an error code so that cron's MAIL_TO would pick it up. This would then obviously clutter crontabs and obviously requires code changes to write a log entry.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM (well, the process associated with it) exits with exit code 1 when an uncaught exception makes all its way to the main thread which doesn't handle it either.

So, one option is to have all your checked exceptions caught in `main()` and exit with anything other than 1 using `System.exit()` (don't exit with 0 either since this is the "standard" for success), and have the cron script handle whatever the exit code is (using the `$?` variable for instance).

Also, don't forget that stack traces go to stderr by default.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a try catch block to catch the out of memory exception and do the necessary thing in catch block.. u could create failure log records and add the job in the log when u reach the catch block

Answer (score 0):

i think best is to store successful completion flag in database or log and then based on count i mean how many time cron should run in a day or week  log or db can be reviewed to see any failures.